# Shuffling bits in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, encryption

As beginner of Python, I thought it'd be good to create a project way beyond my skill to get to know the language. Unfortunately, the most difficult part of the project which involves moving bits around, which functions as an other challenge since I find it difficult to wrap my head around bits. I know what each operator do, I just find it hard to make it do whatever I want.

Clearly I failed, hence this question.

I'm trying to encrypt a string by changing the bit order using a predefined list of indexes. I thought I did a pretty good job, but it's not working and I don't know why.

Even when my code should do the job, I'm very uncertain if it would still work (without errors) with different types of data. Additional feedback is very welcome!

---

test.py

```
import bitshuffle, random

# New bit order
# TODO present this as an int, rather a string
code = "01234567"
code = "".join(random.sample(code, len(code)))

# The data obviously
data = b'Jalape\xc3\xb1o\x00\xff'

encrypted = bitshuffle.encrypt(code, data)
decrypted = bitshuffle.decrypt(code, encrypted)

print data         # Jalapeño�
print encrypted    # �d�d,tGi��
print decrypted    # Jalapeño�
```

---

bitshuffle.py

```
import struct

def encrypt(code, data):
    """
    encrypt(string, string) --> string
    Shuffles bits according to code
    """
    format = str(len(data)) + 'c'

    chars = struct.unpack(format, data)
    args = [format]

    for c in chars:
        dec = ord(c)
        ndec = 0

        for i in xrange(8):
            bit = dec >> i & 1
            ndec = ndec | bit << int(code[i])

        args.append(chr(ndec))

    return struct.pack(*args)

def decrypt(code, data):
    """
    decrypt(string, string) --> string
    Shuffles bits according to code
    """

    format = str(len(data)) + 'c'

    chars = struct.unpack(format, data)
    args = [format]

    for c in chars:
        dec = ord(c)
        ndec = 0

        for i in xrange(8):
            bit = dec >> i & 1
            ndec = ndec | bit << code.find(str(i))

        args.append(chr(ndec))

    return struct.pack(*args)
```

---

## Update (10:32)

As I was fiddling about, I managed to do it. The problem was in the decoding. Sorry if my question wasn't clear earlier. I kind of shifted the bits the wrong way around.

I do still wonder if the current code can accept different types of data though.

Comment: Please describe the expected outcome and the observed outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`7 - code[i]` does not work. You shoudl reverse the `code`.

For example, if the code is `[1, 3, 5, 7, 0, 2, 4, 6]`, reverse should be `[4, 0, 5, 1, 6, 2, 7, 3]`. (`4` in the reverse means the index of `0` in the original code. )

- `code[4] == 0`
- `code[0] == 1`
- `code[5] == 2`
- ...

---

```
>>> import struct
>>>
>>> def encrypt(code, data):
...     return algorithm(code, data)
...
>>> def decrypt(code, data):
...     code = {x:i for i, x in enumerate(code)} # <----
...     return algorithm(code, data)
...
>>> def algorithm(code, data):
...     chars = struct.unpack('c' * len(data), data)
...     args = ['c' * len(data)]
...     for c in chars:
...         dec = ord(c)
...         ndec = 0
...         for i in xrange(8):
...             bit = dec >> i & 1
...             ndec = ndec | bit << code[i]
...         args.append(chr(ndec))
...     return struct.pack(*args)
...
>>> code = [1, 3, 5, 7, 0, 2, 4, 6]
>>> encrypt(code, 'abc')
'\x16\x1c\x1e'
>>> decrypt(code, _)
'abc'
```

Comment: I guess I'm an idiot but I would expect the list you wrote above "reversed" would be... reversed. I don't get what happened to it. Why isn't `[1, 3, 5, 7, 0, 2, 4, 6]` reversed `[6, 4, 2 ... ]`

Comment: @bigbadonk420, I didn't write any "reverse **d**". What do you mean?

Comment: I mean the part where you say "reverse should be" above in your answer.

Comment: @bigbadonk420, Did you read the explanation insdie the parentheses (`4` in the reverse means the index of `0` in the original code) ?

Comment: I understand now, I misinterpreted your answer. Perhaps it would be clearer if you said that `code[4]` resolves to `0` rather than `4` resolves to `0`, I mixed up the index numbering with the actual values :) Anyway, I still don't understand the answer but it's probably just me, so nevermind.

Comment: @falsetru I kinda figured out I wasn't undoing my 'encryption' myself, but your answer is the best, so I accepted it :) I do have a remaining question though: is the code safe for different types of data like ints, blobs and UTF-8 encoded strings?

Comment: @TimS., It only works for bytes string (encoded string). It will not works for unicode string.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified what exactly you're passing as `code`, and why you should need to call `int()` on it - I'm guessing that you're passing numbers between 0 and 7, right?

Well, then one of the problems is that you're always bit-shifting in the same direction, so your "decryption" routine doesn't undo what your "encryption" routine is doing.

Shifting `0b10000000` one bit to the left doesn't wrap around to make it `0b00000001`, it results in `0b100000000`.